# Integrate VIM with MAXIMA

Tags: vim, latex, maxima

I am writing a lot of math an physics texts using Maxima, LaTeX and VIM. I would like to keep the Maxima Code in the LaTeX source and have an option to send a comment block to Maxima and fill in the following maximaout environment with the result.

An example:

```
%<maxima>
%numer:true$
%/* Physical resolution limit of the eye */
%lambda:500E-9$
%d2:0.008$
%x:5000$
%alpha(d):=asin(1.22*lambda/d)$
%a1:alpha(d1)*180/%pi;
%dx(d):=tan(alpha(d))*x$
%dx1:dx(d1);
%</maxima>
```

When I place the cursor within the % 'environment' I would like the vim command to pick up the maxima code, send it to maxima and paste in the result:

```
%<maximaout>
(a1)0.01747521302242873
(a2)0.004368803192105943
(dx1)1.525000070931567
(dx2)0.3812500011083056
%</maximaout>
```

I am currently using a small script and to enter maxima commands directly in vim and paste the result at the cursor position:

```
"call maxima Kalculation in insert mode and paste result
imap <C-S-C> <C-r>=MaximaCalc()<CR><BS>
function MaximaCalc()
    let args = input("maxima:")
    let cmd="vim2maxima.sh " . args . ";"
    let result=system(cmd)
    let result=substitute(result, '\n', "", "g")
    let result=substitute(result, '\$\$', "$", "g")
    return result
endfunction
```

The vim2maxima.sh script takes care of simplyfing the result, converting it to tex and filtering out the TeX part of the Maxima output

```
maxima --very-quiet --batch-string "tex(ratsimp(($*)));" | egrep '^\$\$.+'
```

I would like to improve my crude script to search backwards for `%<maxima>` and forward for `%</maxima>`, remove the `<maxima>` tags and the comment percent signs.

I have no idea how to get the text by searching backwards and forwards in the current VIM buffer. Any tips or pointers?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about how to use Vim for that purpose. Some general comments: (1) If you can isolate the Vim-specific aspect of the question, maybe you can ask in a Vim user forum or other Vim-specific forum. (2) Instead of using Vim to compose the document, maybe use Jupyter. I've created a kernel (i.e. backend code) for Jupyter to connect to Maxima. I can tell you more if you're interested.

Comment: (3) Another possibility is to create appropriate glue code for Knitr to connect to Maxima. Knitr is a non-interactive system for combining text, code, and math, originally for R but plugins have been created for other backends as well. I did some work on a Maxima backend for Knitr but didn't finish it. I can reinvestigate that if you're interested.

Comment: @Floyd, try [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime).